# Change date after 6 hrs in php variable

Tags: php, date

I need to change the shiftdate variable after 05:30 AM. Since i need to generate data from past 24 hrs starting 05:31 AM to Next day 05:30 AM. I tried like this, but its giving previous day every time. Please help.

I want $shiftdate to use in my sql query;

Code:

```
<?php
    if(date('H:i')>="00:00" || date('H:i')<"05:30"){
                      $shiftdate=  date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))-24*60*60);

                  }
                  else if(date('H:i')>"05:30" || date('H:i')<"00:00")
                  {
                      $shiftdate=date('Y-m-d');
                  }

                  echo $shiftdate; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't just compare string like "05:30" as a number and hope for the best. You need to compare numerical value of the hour and then numerical value of the minute.
2. You have a race in between the first `if` and the `else if`
3. Also the `else if` doesn't cover it completely, so if it hit's the sweetspot, you can end up with `$shiftdate` being NULL.
4. Make it a function with protoype `shiftdate_type_whatever_it_is fn_name(int hour, int minute);`. This way you can simply unit test the function for different (think boundary) values of the `date("H:i");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes for this and encapsulate your check into a function:-

```
/**
 * @param DateTime $checkTime
 * @return string
 */
function getShiftDate(DateTime $checkTime)
{
    $shiftDate = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($checkTime->getTimestamp());
    $hours = (int)$checkTime->format('H');
    $minutes = (int)$checkTime->format('i');
    $totalMins = $hours * 60 + $minutes;
    if($totalMins < 330){
        $shiftDate->modify('yesterday');
    }
    return $shiftDate->format('Y-m-d');
}

var_dump(getShiftDate(new DateTime()));
```

Obviously the input to the function may need to be modified as I don't know how you get your date/time, but that won't be a problem. Post a comment if you need help with that.